# How to make Bootstrap navbar semi-responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need my Bootstrap navbar to always display some elements, and auto-collapse other elements. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just create another list (`navbar-nav`) outside of your `class="collapse"` item.

In the following example, link1/2 will always be visible whereas link3/4 will be collapsed on small devices: [JS Fiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/julienvignolles/veaFx/).

**CSS**

```
#navbar1 > li {
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar1">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I just tried your code. Link 1 and Link 2 go on a a new line when the window is sized small. It does not work well. Please try it.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a preview. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: When the window is made small, and the items collapse, the height of navbar increases. I am trying to solve this. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It's basic CSS, you need to override some Bootstrap styles (like `.navbar-nav, .navbar-toggle { margin-bottom: 0; }`). Don't forget to tick my answer if it is fine. ;)

Comment: Don't forget that Bootstrap3 is "mobile first": start with small viewport styles, then work on larger viewports (`@media (min-width: XXXpx) {…}`). CSS will be easier this way.